# Append Url via replaceState prevent Page Reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code below that appends the url. The code works as it should. However, the replaceState didn't work as I thought it would. Basically, I just want the page not to reload/refresh when the url is appended with text. Any suggestions how to fix this?

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#staff-list").on('change', function() {
        history.replaceState(null, null, location.href = "?account=" + $(this).val());
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it. I'll post here anyway for future coder who happens to seek for answers with similar issue.

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#staff-list").on('change', function() {
        history.replaceState(null, null, "?account=" + $(this).val());
      });
    });
  </script>
```